# How can I implement VERP (Variable envelope return path) in .NET?

Tags: .net, email, smtp, email-bounces

I want to implamant this bounce handling protocol in .NET but after I researched abit I found out that the basic classes that come with .NET don't support envelope assignment required by VERP

Is there a work around or another method?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely implement VERP using `System.Net.Mail`, just generate a unique `from` address for each `to` address, then when the message bounces, your `catch-all` email account will receive it and you will know what `to` address to invalidate.

Here's a step-by-step example:

1. You will send an email to `someuser@somedomain.com`.
2. You generate a random unique `from` address from a GUID, for example:
       F9168C5E-CEB2-4faa-B6BF-329BF39FA1E4-customers@mydomain.com
3. You keep a dictionary or database table that associates the `from` address above with the `to` address.
4. You receive a bounce email to a `catch-all` inbox where the recepient is `F9168C5E-CEB2-4faa-B6BF-329BF39FA1E4-customers@mydomain.com`, therefore...
5. You invalidate `someuser@somedomain.com` in your DB.

Comment: Isn't there an issue with envelope from and the standard from address of the email, the System.Net.Mail can't touch the envelope from, will this be an issue with spam filters?

Comment: This is not a practical answer, especially if you are developing a professional mailing system. Recipients often handle spam and have message rules based on who the email was From.  You can not have it being different each time.

Comment: @Talon: Craigslist works this way, as many other systems. Plus, the main goal is to validate the customer address; whether the message goes to spam is irrelevant.