# Sending email with a custom envelope sender (VERP)

Tags: c#, smtp, verp

I'm writing a server that will send email to many recipients on behalf of my client.

The email must come from the client's email address (client@example.org), but I want to automatically handle bounces via [VERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path).  Basically, the email `From:` header will be client@example.org, but the SMTP envelope sender (`MAIL FROM`) will be *unique-email-id*@my-email-service.example.com.

I've already built a multi-threaded sending engine that uses the built-in `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` to actually speak SMTP with the recipient's MX server.

Unfortunately, `SmtpClient` does not allow you to specify the envelope sender – it just uses the `From:` address.

I need an alternative that allows me to specify the SMTP `MAIL FROM`.  Preferably, something that takes little work to drop in and replace `SmtpClient`.

Thus far, everything I've looked at is an entire [email](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) [suite](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/ENG/Products/Mail_Server/mail_index_eng.aspx?type=info) (SMTP/POP3/IMAP/kitchen sink).  What lightweight SMTP libraries are available?

Comment: Hi Josh were you able to find out how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: @DiegoRamos: I did, but unfortunately, this was 10 years ago, so my memory is fuzzy.  I believe I had to use some other SMTP implementation that actually supported VERP, but I don't recall what exactly I used.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` internally is using `mailMessage.Sender ?? mailMessage.From` for the envelope `MAIL FROM` envelope sender.

Unfortunately while you could use the Sender property to specify a envelope `MAIL FROM` envelope sender using the `mailMessage.Sender` property, SmtpClient will also add a `Sender: unique-email-id@domain.com` header.

With this Sender header, the email client then shows a send from `unique-email-id@domain.com on behalf of John Doe <doe@domain.com>`

I found no decent open source Smtp library supporting this – even Mono's SmtpClient lacks this feature. Some libraries supporting VERP:

- MailKit/MimeKit http://www.mimekit.net/
- Afterlogic MailBee
- Limilabs mail.dll
- Emailarchitect EASendMail

PS: feel free to vote for the VERP feature request:  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3800792-smtpclient-should-allow-to-specify-the-envelope-se

related question: [How can I implement VERP (Variable envelope return path) in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050779/how-can-i-implement-verp-variable-envelope-return-path-in-net)